# EFI partition malware?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, malware, efi, md5, rootkit

I have a 2011 Macbook Pro, running 10.8.2 and was worried that the laptop may have been tampered with while left unattended for a few days while abroad in Asia.

I have mounted my EFI partition using:

```
mkdir /Volumes/efi
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
```

In there I have found:

```
├── .Trashes
│   ├── ._502
│   ├── ._508
│   ├── 502
│   └── 508
├── .fseventsd
│   └── fseventsd-uuid
├── BOOTLOG
└── EFI
    └── APPLE
        ├── CACHES
        ├── EXTENSIONS
        │   └── Firmware.scap
        └── FIRMWARE
            ├── 2011MBP15.smc
            └── SmcFlasher.efi
```

I repartitioned the computer and enabled filevault just before New Year's Eve 2013 and so thought it strange that the folder /Volumes/efi/.Trashes/._508 exists and is dated 2 Nov 2012. Also I don't recall ever having had a user with id as high as 508. (Only have 3 accounts and maybe macports?) For the .

Also the file BOOTLOG is dated 3/Nov/2012 with lots of entries for SlingShot, SlingShotUpdateProgressUI, NetworkFinishOSRSHostInfoLookup.

Can anybody explain these artifacts as natural occurrences (i.e., *not* the result of tampering)?
Any suggestions as to other things to check to see whether my machine is infected?

Finally, could someone check the MD5 checksums for the following files:

```
/Volumes/efi/EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS/Firmware.scap 5783b82bc1dd7d612ca0447b737b35df
/Volumes/efi/EFI/APPLE/FIRMWARE/2011MBP15.smc   fbc25d6db9babda6d5d70163c9a48286
/Volumes/efi/EFI/APPLE/FIRMWARE/SmcFlasher.efi  586e3e4775cedb3a5ca821011541b500
```

Comment: Could you add your operating system, currently you state you are running "10.8.2" but you don't specify what OS.

Comment: @washbow: A "2011 Macbook Pro, running 10.8.2" would most likely indicate OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Yup running Mountain Lion